# How Did Aharon Change Moshe's Words to Par'oh?

Tags: words, rashi, moshe-rabbeinu, va-eira, aharon

Moshe's message to Par'oh was to be communicated [through](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88299/for-how-long-was-aharon-moshes-spokesman) Aharon, as per Sh'mot, 7:2

> אַתָּ֣ה תְדַבֵּ֔ר אֵ֖ת כָּל־אֲשֶׁ֣ר אֲצַוֶּ֑ךָּ וְאַהֲרֹ֤ן אָחִ֙יךָ֙ יְדַבֵּ֣ר אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֔ה וְשִׁלַּ֥ח אֶת־בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל מֵאַרְצֽוֹ׃

Rashi explains that this means that Moshe will word things in one way, and (via [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).org)

> וְאַהֲרֹן אָחִיךָ יַמְלִיצֶנּוּ וְיַטְעִימֶנּוּ בְּאָזְנֵי פַרְעֹה
>
> and your brother Aaron shall express it in eloquent language and explain it in Pharaoh’s hearing.

My Rabbis Isaiah/Sharfman linear translation has the phrase as "and Aaron your brother will **interpret it and make it acceptable** in the ears of Pharaoh."

This seems to indicate that Aharon was able to change the specific wording of the messages in order to make them more understandable or "acceptable". Is there any discussion or record of the changes that Aharon made?